# How to solve "TextMate is running on a read-only file system and can therefore not be updated."

Tags: textmate

When using Textmate, I'm regularly prompted to upgrade:

> TextMate 2.0.23 is now available. You have version 2.0.19. Would you like to download it now?

However, if I choose the upgrade option, I immediately see a dialog with this error:

> TextMate is running on a read-only file system and can therefore not be updated.
>
> If you downloaded TextMate from the internet then moving it out of the Downloads folder should solve the problem.

Textmate isn't in my Downloads folder; it's in `/Applications`. Its permissions look like this:

```sh
drwxr-xr-x@  3 sam   staff    96 15 Feb  2021 TextMate.app
```

It wasn't installed via brew, so upgrading it that way isn't an option. How could I do an upgrade? Is removing the app and reinstalling it the only way?

I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H1519).

Comment: What does `ls -ld /Applications` show?

Comment: What OS are you running on this Mac?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, my permissions look like
`drwxrwxr-x   3 clausenator  staff    96 Feb 15  2021 TextMate.app` 
and I am running 10.13.6

Comment: @mmmmmm, `ls -ld /Applications` shows `drwxrwxr-x+ 37 root  admin  1184 10 Nov 16:13 /Applications`

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm running Catalina 10.15.7 (19H1519). I'll add that into the question.

Comment: I'd just delete it and install the new version.